# Box with chocolates probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> I am given a box with 20 chocolates, all of them identical from the outside but 5 of them are with cherry filling, 7 with cream and 8 with nuts.
>   I ate 10 at random. What is the probability I ate at least one of each kind?

My attempt: All different ways to select 10 chocolates out of 20 are 
$C(20,10)$.
Then the required probability is 
$1 - ( C(12,10)+C(13,10)+C(15,10) ) / C(20,10)$

I am getting about 98% but this doesn't seem correct to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems fine to me. This seems to me like a case of the chance of two people having the same birthday. With 23 people you already have over 50% chance of this occurring. So when eating half the chocolates I would be surprised if you did not have one of each.

Comment: This does seem correct to me, it is probably very unlikely that you didn't pick any cherries ($\frac{C(15, 10)}{C(20,10)}$) and even less likely that you didn't pick any cream ($\frac{C(13, 10)}{C(20,10)}$) or nuts ($\frac{C(12, 10)}{C(20,10)}$). Obviously it is impossible that you failed to pick two of the flavours, or otherwise the calculation would have to be a bit more complex, but this way it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that I did not eat any with cherry filling.

Let $B$ be the event that I did not eat any with cream.

Let $C$ be the event that I did not eat any with nuts.

Then with [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we find:

$$P\left(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(A\cup B\cup C\right)=$$$$1-P\left(A\right)-P\left(B\right)-P\left(C\right)+P\left(A\cap B\right)+P\left(A\cap C\right)+P\left(B\cap C\right)-P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)$$

But the events that differ from $A,B,C$ are all empty so that we can
simplify:

$$P\left(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(A\right)-P\left(B\right)-P\left(C\right)=\frac{\binom{20}{10}-\binom{15}{10}-\binom{13}{10}-\binom{12}{10}}{\binom{20}{10}}$$
showing that your solution is correct.

Comment: drhab: if we name R the ones with cherry, C with cream and N with nuts and count all arrangements of length 10 of R, C and N such that $R \leq5$, $C \leq7$, $N \leq8$, we get 42 arrangements in total, of which only 29 include all 3 types; thus the probability is 0.69. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CarlosLopez Your counting is okay. However the arrangements are **not equiprobable** (and you seem to think they are equiprobable). E.g. the probability on $(2,3,5)$ equals $\frac{\binom52\binom73\binom85}{\binom{20}{10}}$ and the probability on $(2,0,8)$ equals $\frac{\binom52\binom70\binom88}{\binom{20}{10}}$. They are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you're right, in general case, you have to use inclusion-exclusion principle to account for situations where you take only one type of sweet for example but no worries here because there is no possibility to choose from only one type.

In general we have something like:

P(not all types taken) = P(taken only from 1 and 2) + P(taken only from 2 and 3) + P(taken only from 3 and 1) - P(taken only from 1) - P(taken only from 2) - P(taken only from 3).

And to feed your intuition, check expected value of each of chocolate type.

Comment: In essence we are looking for different solutions of $x+y+z=10$ where x, y, z are all positive and $x \leq5$, $y \leq7$, $z \leq8$.